# LoggerFields for Syslog (output log priority and stack trace)

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, syslog, papertrail-app

Log4j can send logs to Papertrail using a syslog appender ([documentation](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/java-log4j-logging/)):

```
log4j.appender.syslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.syslog.Facility=LOCAL7 
log4j.appender.syslog.FacilityPrinting=false 
log4j.appender.syslog.Header=true 
log4j.appender.syslog.SyslogHost=<host>.papertrailapp.com:XXXXX
log4j.appender.syslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=%p: (%F:%L) %x %m %n
```

Notice the handy `ConversionPattern` property.

---

I have managed to get something similar rolling for log4j2:

```
Syslog:
  name: Syslog
  id: [my-id]
  appName: [my-app]
  protocol: UDP
  format: RFC5424
  facility: local7
  host: <host>.papertrailapp.com
  port: XXXXX
  includeMDC: true
  mdcId: mdc
```

It works and outputs using the default RFC5424 format:

```
May 14 14:31:36 [server] [app]: My log message
```

---

What I really want is a message with priority information as well as full stack traces:

```
May 14 14:31:36 [server] [app]: ERROR My log message MyException
        at package1.MyClass.method1(MyClass.java:20)
        at ...
```

Looks like [LoggerFields](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) is supposed to do it, but I can't get it to work:

```
 loggerFields:
   LoggerFields:
     KeyValuePair:
       key: priority
       value: "%p"
     KeyValuePair:
       key: exception
       value: "%ex"
```

How can I get Log4j2 to output to syslog using the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting [RFC5424Layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#RFC5424Layout)'s `exceptionPattern` attribute to `%ex`.

Comment: It worked `exceptionPattern: "%ex"`, just need to find a way to put priority information now.

Comment: I tried
`log4j.appender.syslog.layout.ExceptionPattern=%ex`
and
`log4j.appender.syslog.ExceptionPattern=%ex`
I get error: WARN No such property [exceptionPattern] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Comment: I don't see any way for adding log priority with log4j.properties files using LoggerFields. 

Is there any solution for adding log priority?

Comment: Would you mind asking this on the Log4j2 user mailing list?